Runge-Kutta method approaches exact solution
Task:
We consider the following ODE: $$ y' = \lambda \cdot (y-\phi(t)) \cdot \phi'(t) $$ with $ y(0) =y_0 = \phi(0)$ and $\Re(\lambda) \leq 0$, using the Runge-Kutta method. Show that the approximations $\eta_l^{(k)}$ of the time derivatives $y'(t_k + \Delta t\cdot c_l)$ approach the exact values as $\lambda \rightarrow - \infty $ but this only holds for $y_{k+1} = y_k + \sum_{l=1}^m b_l \cdot \eta_l^{(k)} $ if $A_{m,l} = b_l$ for all $l = 1,\dots,m$.
My work:
My plan is to first determine the exact solution. Then determine a form for $y_{k+1}$ and finally compare the terms assuming that $\lambda \rightarrow - \infty $. Ok first the exact solution: For $ y' = \lambda \cdot y $ We have the solution $ y = c \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot t} $. Then I consider the equation $ c(t) \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot t} = y(t) $. I get the result that $c'(t) = \frac{\phi'(t) - \lambda \cdot \phi(t)}{e^{\lambda \cdot t}}$. So $c(t) = \phi(t) \cdot e^{-\lambda \cdot t} $. Finally we can determine the exact solution $ \phi(t) \cdot e^{-\lambda \cdot t} \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot t} = \phi(t) = y(t) $. Pretty sure this part is okay.
But Im struggling with the Runge-Kutta method, we have:
$y_{k+1} = y_k + \sum_{l=1}^m b_l \cdot \eta_l^{(k)} $ and $\eta_l^{(k)} = f(t_k + \Delta c_l, y_k + \Delta t \sum_{j=1}^m A_{l,j} \eta_j^{(k)}) $. We could maybe substitute that into the ODE?:
$$ \eta_l^{(k)} = \lambda \cdot (y_k + \Delta t \sum_{j=1}^m A_{l,j} \eta_j^{(k)}-\phi(t_k + \Delta c_l)) \cdot \phi'(t_k + \Delta c_l) $$
Also in a similiar article Ive read that for $f(t,y) = \lambda \cdot y $, the following system of equations arises for the stages of the Runge-Kutta method:
$ n^{(k)} = \lambda \cdot (y_k \cdot e + \Delta t A n^{(k)}) $ with $ e = (1,\dots,1)^T $ and the Runge-Kutta step can be expressed in vector notation as $ y_{k+1} = y_k + \Delta t b^T n^{(k)} $ Maybe we could use something similiar here as well.
Also I think that we need the condition of the the task $A_{m,l} = b_l$ for all $l = 1,\dots,m$ only at the end.
Can you help me out? Thank you in advance.

General solution is
$$y(t)=\frac{1}{\lambda}\cdot(1-e^{\lambda\cdot(\phi(t)-y_0)})+\phi(t)$$

If $y(t) = \phi(t)$ you'd have $y'(t) = 0$, so this can't be right unless $\phi$ happens to be constant.
